# Build failing on TravisCI with no logs

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I am setting up a project to use TravisCI, however when I push to github and trigger the build it fails and there are no logs. I am looking for a way to debug what the issue is, but it is hard (obviously) with no logs.

Here is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: java
sudo: false
script: mvn clean verify
```

Here is the out put on TravisCI:

[image]

When I run the command `mvn clean verify` in my project directory everything works and the build is succesful.

I am wondering if there is some way I can dig deeper into what is going wrong or if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: The 'sudo false' setting is no longer available, have you tried removing it? Ref: https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-11-19-required-linux-infrastructure-migration